# MS Access 2010 value of MemberID where FinishDate = NULL

Tags: ms-access

Using MS Access 2010

My Table BranchMemberOffice has the following columns:

BranchID

OfficeID

MemberID

FinishDate

Below works but I need the value of  MemberID  where FinishDate = NULL

```
strBranchID = Combo221.Column(0)

strOfficeID = 1
strChair = DLookup("MemberID", "BranchMemberOffice", "BranchID = " & strBranchID & " AND OfficeID = " & strOfficeID)
```

Hope I am clear enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table structure is like this (I've not added any Primary Keys):
[image]

This code will return MemberID 11:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim MemberID As Variant 'Changed from Long to accept Nulls.
    Dim lOfficeID As Long
    Dim lBranchID As Long

    lOfficeID = 3
    lBranchID = 1

    MemberID = DLookup("MemberID", "BranchMemberOffice", _
        "BranchID=" & lBranchID & " AND OfficeID=" & lOfficeID & _
        " AND FinishDate Is Null")

    If IsNull(MemberID) Then
        MsgBox "No value returned."
    Else
        MsgBox MemberID & " is the value returned."
    End If

End Sub
```

**Edit:** Nearly forgot - `MemberID` in the code above must be defined as a `Variant`.  Keeping it as a `Long` will return "Invalid use of Null" if the result is Null - a Long can't hold a Null value, while a Variant can.

**Edit 2:** Have added a message box to show how to deal with Null values.

Comment: Darren that did the trick thank you so much I was breaking my head :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
strChair = DLookup("MemberID", "BranchMemberOffice", "FinishDate Is Null")
```

Comment: I've tried this but no success:   [code] strChair = DLookup("MemberID", "BranchMemberOffice", "BranchID = " & strBranID & " AND OfficeID = " & strOfficeID & " AND FinishDate = Null)[code]

Comment: `FinishDate IS Null"`.  You've missed a final " and used `= Null` rather than `Is Null`.  Is `strOfficeId` and `strBranID` a number or text?  Also - `strBranID` in your comment and `strBranchID` in your post.

Comment: Okay I think I am on the wrong path here. I have a table called BranchMemberOffice wich has the following columns MemberID, BranchID,  OfficeID and FinishDate.  I know the BranchID to look for I know OfficeID both numbers but I need the value of MemberID in combination with the FinishDate that should be Null